# Why can't delete the space after the variable?

Tags: python

I can't seem to get rid of the space between `age1` and `?` in my final line. I tried adding `+` but all I get is a syntax error. Can anyone help me with this?

```
    name = input("What's your name? ")
    print("")
    print("Hi " + name + "!")

    age1 = int(input("How old are you? "))
    age2 = age1/2+7

    print(age1, "? Cool! Just remember that you can't date anyone younger than " + format(age2,"0.0f") + "!")
```

Answer (score 2):

> I tried adding '+' but all I get is a syntax error.

You need to *replace* `,` with `+`:

```
print(age1 + "? Cool! Just remember that you can't date anyone younger than " + format(age2,"0.0f") + "!")
```

As of Python 3.6, this can be written better using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)<sup>1</sup>:

```
print(f"{age1}? Cool! Just remember that you can't date anyone younger than {age2:0.0f}!")
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Previous versions of Python also offered different formatting options but these are mostly of historical interest now.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(str(age1) + "? Cool! Just remember that you can't date anyone younger than " + format(age2,"0.0f") + "!")
```